# Approximating path with shapes?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, drawing, image-trace

Let's say I have a triangle that I drew with a pen so it's not perfect. I then upload it to illustrator and image trace it into a vector. It's now clean but still not perfect. Is there a way to approximate it into a real triangle? Similarly approximate an imperfect circle into a perfect circle.

### Edit:

Redrawing it in illustrator using shape tools is not an option. the image I'm working with is too complex to do that and it will take a very long time. I just want to be able to perfect it using some kind of algorithm on illustrator. simplifying the path doesn't work.

Comment: Why would you merely not use the Polygonal Tool in Illustrator and draw a triangle??

Comment: @Scott see edited question

Comment: @ooolb this is not an entirely trivial problem.IF a computer could automatically infer wat your thinking a lot fo things would become easy. However it is hard to device any strategy since your not supplying with any infor of the nature of your data. For example if we know that the data only contains triangles and cricles then yes no problem, but if they are anything at all then classification need to be much more ecarefully thought out. So if possible toshare some characteristic data thn wa can at least start thinking of a strategy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I'm aware, there's no option or script to redefine an imperfect polygon to a perfect polygon. (I could be wrong though)

However...

**Illustrator CC** has the **Shaper Tool** which may be helpful.

You could manually draw on a new layer merely *approximating* the shapes to get actual precise shapes:

[image]

Comment: thanks I will most likely end up doing this. If only there was a script that took sharper tool onto already drawn lines. that would be ideal.

Comment: is there a version of sharper that does non-perfect shapes like isosceles triangles or curves (like how lazy nezumi does curves in photoshop)?

Comment: Lazi Nuzami is a Windows Only plug in.. never touched it.  AstuteGraphics DrawScribe may be close though. -- You're asking for precision when you want it and then imprecision when you want it. I don't think software is smart enough in general to tell which is which and when to use what in *any* sort of automated fashion. It can do one or the other... but it's still up to the user to determine when to use which and what method to use. There's *honestly* no substitute for *manual* creation.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to write a basic jsx to draw the triangles at each selected item. The function below will resize the drawn triangles to match both height and width of each selection. If you want triangle proportions maintained, use only height or width.

```
DrawTrianglesAt (activeDocument.selection);

function DrawTrianglesAt (items)
{ var count, i, s, tri;
  count = items.length;
  for (i=0; i<count; i++)
  { s = items[i];
    tri = s.parent.pathItems.polygon (0, 0, 1, 3);
    tri.fillColor = s.fillColor;
    tri.strokeColor = s.strokeColor;
    tri.top= s.top, tri.left = s.left;
    tri.height = s.height, tri.width = s.width;
  }
}
```